Ni la IA me puede asistir
Estoy aprendiendo desde cero Java, llevo una semana intentando terminar esta tarea, creo que algo no estoy viendo en las instrucciones. Se las adjunto aquí
Escribe un programa que actúe como una calculadora como en las lecciones anteriores, pero ahora obtendrá la entrada del usuario hasta que introduzca **e. El cálculo será en el formato **operación, float, float (separado por una nueva línea), donde las operaciones posibles son +,-,,/. Cada salida (resultado del cálculo) está separada por una nueva línea. Comprueba los casos de prueba para ver ejemplos. Para obtener la entrada de un char usa, char c = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0); Puede que necesites saltarte una línea para poder usar sólo scanner.nextLine()*
Esto es lo que llevo de mi código, pero no sé si deba usar de primero for y luego if y como imprimo ambos resultados
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        char c = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
        float n1 = scanner.nextFloat();
        float n2 = scanner.nextFloat();
        float res= 0;
         
        if (c == '+') {
            res = n1 + n2;
        }
        else if (c == '-') {
            res = n1 - n2;
        }
        else if (c == '*') {
            res = n1 * n2;
        }
        else if (c == '/') {
            res = n1 / n2;
        }
    
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}

Actualización: Se me olvido agregar que deben salir dos resultados posibles


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Y cual es el problema?

Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor aca. Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. El código y los mensajes de error siempre como texto, con formato, tal como ya te indicaron. 2. Pon un título descriptivo a la pregunta. 3. ¿Cuál es el problema?

MEjor.. pero seguimos sin saber cual es el problema de este codigo...

Tu confianza en la IA es infundada.

No uses scanner.nextLine().charAt(0). Se supone que la operación y los números están en la misma línea. Usa scanner.next() para obtener la operación u obten la línea con scanner.nextLine() y extrae de ella el operador y los números. Puedes usar regex para eso.

Si la entrada viene asi, entonces si necesitas un for primero...

llego un poco tarde, pero vamos igual...
Pensemos el programa por partes:

el usuario va a ingresar una cadena conteniendo operandos y operadores.
a) debemos extraer del mismo, los distintos componentes y guardarlos.

realizamos las operaciones.

mostramos el resultado


En el primer paso, vamos a recibir una cadena similar a:
"+\n4\n5\n*\n4\n6\ne"  // "\n" es el símbolo de nueva linea

Esta cadena es ideal para generar un 'array', separandola por sus saltos de linea, para ello usamos el método split(""), enviándole como parámetro, el "divisor".
String partes[] = cadenaEntrada.split( "\n" );

Si hay un 'array'... puede que haya un 'for', este nos ayudará a separar la paja del trigo.
Antes declaramos la variables en las que almacenaremos los datos.
int numeros[] = new int[ 2 ];
String operación = "";

  // como no sabemos cuantas operaciones pueden "venir", hacemos al bucle infinito,   
  // colocando "condicion" como "true". 

boolean condicion = true; 
for( int i = 0; condicion; i += 3 ) {

     // este bucle, itera sobre los componentes de cada operación
   for( int k = i; k < 3; k++ ) {

         // primero verificamos que la cadena actual sea "e", en cuyo caso ponemos
         // condición en "false" que nos saca del primer bucle y "break" que nos saca 
         // del segundo y evita la ejecución de la llamada a "operar"
       if( partes[ k + i ].equals( "e" )) {
          condicion = false;
          break;
       }
       else if( k == 0 ) { 
            // como "k" va de "0" a "2", le debemos agregar el desplazamiento 
            // provocado por "i"
          operacion = partes[ k + i ];  
       }
       else {
          numeros[ k - 1 ] = Integer.parseInt( partes[ k + i ] );
       }
    }
    if( condicion ) {
       operar( numeros, operacion );
    }
}

Acá va el código completo:
void resolverOperaciones( String cadenaEntrada ) {
   String partes[] = cadenaEntrada.split( "\n" );
   int numeros[] = new int[ 2 ];
   String operacion = "";
   boolean condicion = true;
   for( int i = 0; condicion; i += 3 ) {
      for( int k = 0; k < 3; k ++ ) {
         System.out.println( " k = " + k );
         if( partes[ k + i ].equals( "e" ) ) {
            condicion = false;
            break;
         }
         if( k == 0 ) {
            operacion = partes[ k + i];
         }
         else {
            numeros[ k - 1 ] = Integer.parseInt( partes[ k ] );
         }
      }
      if( condicion ) operar( numeros, operacion );
   }
}

void operar( int num[], String ope ) {
   String texto[] = { "El resultado de ", "' es igual a: '", "'" }; 
   String operacion[] = new String[ 2 ];
   switch( ope) {
      case "+":
         operacion[ 0 ] = "sumar '";
         operacion[ 1 ] = "' más '";
         System.out.println( texto[ 0 ] + operacion[ 0 ]  + 
                 num[ 0 ] + operacion[ 1 ]  + num[ 1 ] +
                 texto[ 1 ] + ( num[ 0 ] + num[ 1 ]) + texto[ 2 ] );
         break;
      case "-":
         operacion[ 0 ] = "restar '";
         operacion[ 1 ] = "' menos '";
         System.out.println( texto[ 0 ] + operacion[ 0 ]  + 
                 num[ 0 ] + operacion[ 1 ]  + num[ 1 ] +
                 texto[ 1 ] + ( num[ 0 ] - num[ 1 ]) + texto[ 2 ] );
         break;
      case "*":
         operacion[ 0 ] = "multiplicar '";
         operacion[ 1 ] = "' por '";
         System.out.println( texto[ 0 ] + operacion[ 0 ]  + 
                 num[ 0 ] + operacion[ 1 ]  + num[ 1 ] +
                 texto[ 1 ] + ( num[ 0 ] * num[ 1 ]) + texto[ 2 ] );
         break;
      case "/":
         operacion[ 0 ] = "dividir '";
         operacion[ 1 ] = "´ dividido '";
         System.out.println( texto[ 0 ] + operacion[ 0 ]  + 
                 num[ 0 ] + operacion[ 1 ]  + num[ 1 ] +
                 texto[ 1 ] + ( num[ 0 ] / num[ 1 ]) + texto[ 2 ] );
   }
   System.out.println( "" );
}

